# xenserver, fedora guest ext grow ext4 partition

Tags: fedora, xenserver

I've got a partition on a guest fedora system running in xenserver. Originally the size of the partition was 400GB.  I recently extended the size to 600GB.  It now shows in the xenserver console as being 600GB, however, when I get the disk size from the vm it is still reporting the old size.

```
/dev/xvdc1      394G  314G   61G  84%
```

I tired to resize the partition so that it would recognize the new size..

```
[root@fedora ~]# resize2fs /dev/xvdc1
resize2fs 1.41.14 (22-Dec-2010)
The filesystem is already 104857344 blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

Not really sure how to progress here, any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, which basically involved using gparted to resize the disk

Comment: What was the solution?

Comment: Glad you resolved this issue. Please be sure to mark your answer as "accepted" when you are able.